# How to find the smallest number in a mongo query?

Tags: java, mongodb, sorting, mongo-java

I have the following objects in my mongo db:

```
{
  "type" : "timetype"
  "time" : "18"
}
{
  "type" : "timetype"
  "time" : "5"
}
{
  "type" : "timetype"
  "time" : "43"
}
{
  "type" : "timetype"
  "time" : "23"
}
```

And my java code looks like:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
query.put("type", "timetype");

 //I don't know what to put in the (...)
DBCursor cursor = Collection.find(query).sort(...).limit(1);
```

I would like to find the entry with the smallest time in my mongo database that meets the query parameter but I don't know what to put in sort to make that happen.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#sort(com.mongodb.DBObject)

Comment: How would I know about sort and limit if I didn't read the documentation?  I don't know what the goes in the sort is it something like: {"time" : 1}?  Down-voting and then linking the documentation isn't helpful.

Comment: @Grammin It is easy to try out these kinds of things in mongo shell. Learning basic use of the shell will speed up the development as you can iteratively try out e.g. new kind of queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
Collection.find(query).sort(new BasicDBObject( "time" , 1 )).limit(1);
```

should work.